# How to obtain info from raise_application_error()?

Tags: oracle, exception, stored-procedures, plsql

```
...PROCEDURE...
.....
WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLCODE || ' ' || SQLERRM);
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20021, 'Attempted to add duplicate primary key into table A2PROD');
.....
```

**Result:**

```
-1 ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYSTEM.SYS_C004235) violated
```

**I want to show the result as:**

```
-20021 ORA-20021 Attempted to add duplicate primary key into table A2PROD
```

I tried to put the DOPL after the raise_application_error function but still not working.
I want to raise an application error and obtain the error message and code to print them to the output console of oracle developer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure that I understand the problem.  If `DOPL` is an abbreviation for `dbms_output.put_line` and you want `SQLCODE` to be -20021 and `SQLERRM` to be "ORA-20021: Attempted to add duplicate primary key into table A2PROD", you'd need to put the `dbms_output.put_line` call in an exception handler that catches your custom error message.  You could, of course, also do something like

```
WHEN dup_val_on_index
THEN
  l_err_code := -20021;
  l_err_msg  := 'Attempted to add duplicate primary key into table A2PROD';
  dbms_output.put_line( l_err_code || ' ' || l_err_msg );
  raise_application_error( l_err_code, l_err_msg );
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the posted procedure called from another procedure?  Or are you running it some other way?

RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR passes the exception number and its message to the calling program.  So what does *that* do with the exception? For instance, if it has a poor exception handler, like this ...

```
     your_proc_here(p_new_id=>1);
exception
    when others then
        null;
end;
```

... you would never see the -20021 error, just the DBMS_OUTPUT output.